# How to add a filter to a custom post type to get adjacent custom posts via the REST API

Tags: custom-post-types, rest-api

I need to get the adjecent posts of a custom post type "projects". The custom post type works in general and I get the a projects list and single projects via GET request. In addition want to add the adjecent projects for simple navigation on the single project page in the response.

I am using

```
'rest_base'     => 'projects'
```

The below code works for standard posts and I am trying to figure out how to adapt it so I can access the custom post in the same way. How do I access the custom post type correctly? Any help appreciated.

```
function chrest_adjacent_posts( $response, $post, $request ) {
    global $post;
    $next = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false );
    $previous = get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
    $response->data['next'] = ( is_a( $next, 'WP_Post') ) ? array( "id" => $next->ID, "slug" => $next->post_name ) : null;
    $response->data['previous'] = ( is_a( $previous, 'WP_Post') ) ? array( "id" => $previous->ID, "slug" => $previous->post_name ) : null;
    return $response;
}

add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'chrest_adjacent_posts', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: The proper way to do this with REST, I believe, would be to make a request to the normal endpoint, just using the `after` and `before` properties to get posts made before and after the current post.

Comment: Thanks Jakob, as far as I can remember these properies are related to posts before and after a certain date, I  will look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That filter is actually dynamic, so you'll just need to append your post type:

```
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_projects', 'chrest_adjacent_posts', 10, 3 );
```

https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/develop/lib/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php#L1355

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Awesomeness, that was the missing piece! Many thanks!